# Only run a highlighting rule as a nextgroup in syntax file?

Tags: vim, syntax, highlight

I have these rules in a custom syntax file.

```
syn match id '\w\+'
syn keyword _type void int bool string list nextgroup=id
```

I only want `id` to be matched after a `_type`.

Comment: Can you give examples of what should be highlighted and would shouldn't be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're already close.

- To avoid that the *id* group matches anywhere else, just add `contained`.
- For `nextgroup=...`, the match must begin exactly after the end of the current group. Therefore, you need to include the leading whitespace in the *id* group match: `\s\+`, or add `skipwhite`.
- The naming convention for syntax groups is to prepend them with your syntax name; I've used `my...` here.

```
:syn match myId '\w\+' contained
:syn keyword myType void int bool string list nextgroup=myId skipwhite
```

Comment: Adding `skipwhite` after `nextgroup=myId` is probably better. Thanks!

Comment: @KennethCheng Great idea! I've incorporated that in my answer.

Comment: This is not working if you have a rule that contains ALL (like parenthesis matching). `contained` causes the match to only trigger when contained inside SOMETHING - still not ONLY when following `myType`